# Map functions basics in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm self learning Haskell and have come across an issue with the `map` function and was looking for help. What i'm trying to do is take a list of lists and if a list is empty so is `[]` and one of the other lists has a `1` in the head. Then to take that `1` and put it in the `[]` list.

```
a = [[2,1,3,1],[],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]
```

and make it

```
a = [[2,1,3,1],[1],[2,3],[2,3],[4]]
```

so far I have something along the lines of I haven't got the complete thing.

```
((map (\k-> if ([])&&(elem 1 heads))a) 
where heads = map head a
```

But I also have to have it so that if `a = [[1,2,1,3,1],[],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]`
will give `a = [[2,1,3,1],[1],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]` so it only moves one `1` to the empty list.

I know this wont work, but I have been trying to do it for a couple of hours now but i'm not getting anywhere

Comment: And if there aren't any other lists with `1` in the head? Leave the empty list empty?

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to mention that. Just realised I need an then and else

Comment: When searching for a list that starts with `1`, do you want to check only lists after the current empty list or they may be wherever in the list of lists, even before the current empty list?

Comment: all the heads of the lists. So the it could be `a = [[1,3,1],[],[2,3],[9,1,2,3],[4]]` and would give `a = [[3,1],[1],[2,3],[9,1,2,3],[4]]`

Comment: And what if the number of empty lists doesn't match the number of lists with `1` in the head? If there are extra `1`s, which ones do you want to steal? If there are extra `[]`s, which do you want to leave empty?

Comment: `map` might not be the best approach here since you're not uniformly applying a function to all elements.  Perhaps, an explicit recursion fits better.  Also, I think you want to have these two actions happen both or none at all.  So the number of total numbers stay invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is straightforward if approached from the right direction. As a first approximation, you can define your function as a left fold over the input list:

```
fun :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
fun z xss = newList 
  where (foundZ, newList, _) = foldl ... (False, [], False) xss
```

Note that the fold will return two values, namely the resulting list and a boolean indicating if a 1 (or in this case, the parameter `z`) is found in the list. The third parameter indicates if a list has already been replaced (we only want to do one replacement). If we are clever (and we will be) we can use the value of `foundZ` inside the body of the function passed to `foldl` - that is, we can use it before it has apparently been computed. All that is left is to write the argument function to foldl:

```
\(fn,xss',rpl) xs ->
  case xs of 
    ...
```

Consider the different possibilities for `xs`: it is the empty list, it is the list containing a `z` as its head, and every other list:

```
    [] | not rpl -> ...
    (x:r) | x == z && not fn -> ...
    _  -> (fn, xs:xss',rpl)
```

Note that when we check for `x == z` we also check `not fn` because we only want to take a single `z` from a single list, so if we already found one, we do not want to do that again. In the case for the empty list, we check for `not rpl` for the same reason. The last case is obvious, but the first two may not be.

```
    [] | not rpl -> (fn, (if foundZ then [z] else []):xss', True)
```

The case for the empty list simple checks if the `z` was found - if so, it returns a singleton list containing that `z`.

```
    (x:r) | x == z && not fn -> (True , r:xss', rpl)
```

The case for the list starting with a `z` returns `True` for `found` and prepends the *tail* of that list to the result (this is how the 1 gets removed).

Put it all together and you get a simple function:

```
fun :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
fun z xss = reverse newList 
  where (foundZ, newList, _) = 
          foldl 
            (\(fn,xss',rpl) xs ->
              case xs of 
                [] | not rpl -> (fn, (if foundZ then [z] else []):xss', True)
                (x:r) | x == z && not fn -> (True , r:xss', rpl) 
                _  -> (fn, xs:xss', rpl)
            ) (False, [], False) xss
```

and

```
>fun 1 [[2,1,3,1],[],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]
[[2,1,3,1],[1],[2,3],[2,3],[4]]
>fun 1 [[1,2,1,3,1],[],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]
[[2,1,3,1],[1],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]
```

Comment: I'm getting an `indentation or brackets mismatched` error on the `foldl`. but this look like a great solution

Comment: The code [compiles](http://codepad.org/Z9TUqu7Q) - perhaps you have not copied a parentheses or changed the indentation by mistake.

Comment: I think whe i copied it the indentations got moved

Comment: Quick question, whats `fn`?

Comment: It is the parameter bound in the function `(\(fn,xss') xs -> ...)`, and it indicates whether or not `z` has been found in the list seen so far.

Comment: Also with this if you give `a=[[1,2],[],[],[]]` you get `a=[[2],[1],[1],[1]]` is there a way to stop this

Answer (score 3):

Here I attempted to write easy-to-understand functional solution for a
beginner. This can be implemented more efficiently, of course.

```hs
doStuff :: Integral a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
doStuff xs = let n = min holes donors in go n n xs
  where go _ _ []          = []
        go 0 m ([]:ys)     = []     : go 0       m ys
        go n m ([]:ys)     = [1]    : go (n - 1) m ys
        go n 0 ((1:zs):ys) = (1:zs) : go n       0 ys
        go n m ((1:zs):ys) = zs     : go n (m - 1) ys
        go n m (y:ys)      = y      : go n m       ys
        holes              = count null    xs
        donors             = count goodish xs
        count f            = length . filter f
        goodish (1:_)      = True
        goodish _          = False
```

It even works:

```hs
λ> doStuff [[2,1,3,1],[],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]
[[2,1,3,1],[1],[2,3],[2,3],[4]]
λ> doStuff [[1,2,1,3,1],[],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]
[[2,1,3,1],[1],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4]]
λ> doStuff [[1,2,1,3,1],[],[2,3],[1,2,3],[4],[],[]]
[[2,1,3,1],[1],[2,3],[2,3],[4],[1],[]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's going to be a horribly fussy problem to solve in an incremental fashion. Therefore, I suggest you think about monolithic solutions. Start off by counting the total number of empty lists and the total number of lists that start with `1`. Armed with these results, attack the original input again. The counting is easily done using `foldl'` if you're familiar with that, or you could use explicit recursion, or if you don't care about efficiency you could filter and count twice; the final attack will be easiest using explicit recursion.

Comment: Ok, whats the best way to use `foldl`?

Answer (score 0):

IMO `map` isn't really the right function for this job. Conceptually `map` transforms each element of a collection using a function that only looks at the element itself. Obviously you can write a `map` where the function uses "external" variables using lambdas, scoping etc. but I suggest staying as close to the concept of `map` as possible.

The idea of "take that 1 and put it in the [] list." implies (take and put) an imperative approach with side-effects, something we want to avoid as much as possible in a purely functional language as haskell.

You can think about it in another way: there is no need to actually "move" the `1`, i.e. to know which `1` ends up in which `[]`. Counting the number of empty lists (let's call it `x`) and the number of lists that start with `1` (`y`) is enough, we just have then to create a new lists that

- replaces the first `min(x,y)` occurrences of empty lists with `[1]`
- Takes the `tail` of the first `min(x,y)` lists that start with `1`

A probably improvable implementation:

```
redistributeOnes :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
redistributeOnes xs = redistributeOnes' n n xs where
  n = min (length $ filter (==[]) xs) (length $ filter (\l -> if l == [] then False else (head l) == 1) xs)
  redistributeOnes' _ _ [] = []
  redistributeOnes' 0 0 xs = xs
  redistributeOnes' n m ([]:xs) | n > 0 = [1] : redistributeOnes' (n-1) m xs
                                | otherwise = [] : redistributeOnes' n m xs
  redistributeOnes' n m (x:xs)  | head x == 1 && m > 0 = (tail x) : redistributeOnes' n (m-1) xs
                                | otherwise = x : redistributeOnes' n m xs
```

Tests:

```
λ> redistributeOnes [[], [1,2]]
[[1],[2]]
λ> redistributeOnes [[], [1,2], [], [], [1,2,3]]
[[1],[2],[1],[],[2,3]]
λ> redistributeOnes [[], [1,2], [], [1,2,3]]
[[1],[2],[1],[2,3]]
λ> redistributeOnes [[]]
[[]]
λ> redistributeOnes [[], [1,2,3]]
[[1],[2,3]]
λ> redistributeOnes [[1,2,3]]
[[1,2,3]]
λ> redistributeOnes [[1,2,3], [], [], [], [2,5,1], [1,2], [], [1,100]]
[[2,3],[1],[1],[1],[2,5,1],[2],[],[100]]
```